# Automatic Playback of Audio Stream in Browser with Azure Text-to-Speech Streaming

Tags: reactjs, audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I'm currently working on developing a customer service chatbot using Azure's speech service. My project involves using React.js for the client side and FastAPI for the server side. While the setup generally works well, I've encountered an unusual issue: the browser automatically plays the audio stream received from the server, even without an  HTML tag present in my application. Moreover, my code for handling audio streaming isn't functioning as expected.

Here's the relevant React code for reference:

```js
const SpeechRecongnition = ({
  setMessages,
  getHistory,
}: SpeechRecorderProps) => {
  const {
    startRecording,
    stopRecording,
    audioBlob,
    isRecording,
    clearAudioBlob,
  } = useAudioRecorder();
  const audioRef = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>(null);
  const [audioUrl, setAudioUrl] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

  const toggleRecording = () => {
    if (isRecording) {
      stopRecording();
    } else {
      startRecording();
    }
  };
  /***
   * todo: solve the error:"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found."
   *use the stream to send the speech back
   */
  const sendDataToServer = async (audioBlob: Blob | null) => {
    if (audioBlob) {
      // Create a FormData object
      const formData = new FormData();
      // Append the audio data to the FormData object
      formData.append('data', audioBlob, 'recording.wav');
      const response = await sendSpeechToTextRequest(
        formData,
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/chat-speech-to-text/`
      );
      const responseAudio = await sendTextToSpeechRequest(
        response,
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/chat-text-to-speech/`
      );
      setAudioUrl(responseAudio.audio); // Set the audio URL
      await getHistory(setMessages);
    } else {
      console.log('no audio chunks or audio is not recorded correctly!');
    }
  };

  //play the audio mediaBlobUrl is not null
  useEffect(() => {
    if (audioUrl && audioRef.current) {
      const audio = audioRef.current;
      audio.src = audioUrl;

      const audioPromise = audio.play();
      if (audioPromise !== undefined) {
        audioPromise
          .then(() => {
            console.log('play success');
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log('play error', error);
            console.log(`Failed audio URL: ${audioUrl}`); // Log the problematic URL
          });
      }

      audio.onended = () => {
        setAudioUrl(undefined); // Clear the audioUrl state
        audio.src = ''; // Clear the audio element's src
        clearAudioBlob(); // Clear the audio blob
      };
    }
  }, [audioUrl]);
  //call the sendDataToServer function when mediaBlobUrl is not null
  useEffect(() => {
    if (audioBlob) {
      sendDataToServer(audioBlob);
    }
  }, [audioBlob]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleRecording}>
        {isRecording ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}
      </button>
      <audio ref={audioRef} controls hidden />
    </div>
  );
};

export default SpeechRecongnition;
```

This is how I handle the request in React:

```js
# Define text to speech chat route
@app.post("/chat-text-to-speech/")
async def chat_text_to_speech(data: Chat_Request):
    # Send the text to the LLM and get the response
    response = response_from_LLM(data.message)

    # Check if the response is successful
    if response:
        # Convert the response to speech
        audio_stream = text_to_speech(response["response"])

        if  audio_stream:
           return StreamingResponse(audio_stream, media_type='audio/wav')
        else:
            return {"error": "Unable to synthesize audio"}
    else:
        return {"error": "Unable to get response from LLM"}
```

And here's the FastAPI handling code:

```js
# Define text to speech chat route
@app.post("/chat-text-to-speech/")
async def chat_text_to_speech(data: Chat_Request):
    # Send the text to the LLM and get the response
    response = response_from_LLM(data.message)

    # Check if the response is successful
    if response:
        # Convert the response to speech
        audio_stream = text_to_speech(response["response"])

        if  audio_stream:
           return StreamingResponse(audio_stream, media_type='audio/wav')
        else:
            return {"error": "Unable to synthesize audio"}
    else:
        return {"error": "Unable to get response from LLM"}
```

In the browser console, I've encountered the following error messages:

*"play error DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found."*

*"Failed audio URL: blob:http://localhost:5173/2e0d0404-1cbf-4c88-9a50-d37dc0141ae1"*

From these messages, it's clear that the  tag API isn't functioning properly. However, the audio clip still plays in the browser. This occurs even after I removed the  tag from my application and modified the request to return an empty string:

```
return (
<div>
  <button onClick={toggleRecording}>
    {isRecording ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}
  </button>
</div>
```

);

I've confirmed that the issue isn't with the FastAPI server, as returning None in the route stops the audio playback.

Although the application seems to be working fine otherwise, I'm curious to understand why this automatic playback is happening. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to prevent the browser from automatically playing the audio stream and instead allow the  tag to control playback.

Thank you in advance for your help!